# Fluid Simulation Outflow behaves unexpectedly. What are possible remedies?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

- A fluid simulation has one or more fluid outflows.
- One of the fluid outflows does change/delete the fluid, yet only at the boundaries/surface as depicted above. The expectation is any fluid should be deleted by volume. In the image above the expectation is the blue fluid on the upper portion should have been deleted.
- The outflow has volume initialization.
- Normals have been inspected and calculated to the outside.
- The outflow boundary goes across the image left to right and is highlighted in orange.  The outflow is in the shape of the english letter C in 3D.
- Outflow volumes have worked many times in the past for me.  Will Blender put messages in the console if it has problems?